# Why are C++20 template lambdas using typename keyword?

Tags: c++, typename, c++20, generic-lambda

I understand the consistency argument, but most of the parameters for templates are types so I feel that since lambdas are meant to be concise way of defining a struct it probably should have been defaulted to `typename`/`class`(you would still need to write `int/size_t/short`).

If somebody is not familiar with changes to lambdas in C++20 here is the example:

```
[]<typename T>(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for(const auto& x : v) { std::cout << x; }
};
```

and my question is why not:

```
[]<T>(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for(const auto& x : v) { std::cout << x; }
};
```

Comment: `[](const std::vector<auto> &v) { };` works in GCC9, though I'm not sure that is standard. I think the concepts TS allowed such a syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that this *already* has a meaning:

```
template <T> void foo();
```

It's a function template with one template parameter that is a **non-type** template parameter whose type is `T`, and that template parameter has no name.

It would be pretty confusing if the same syntax meant *very* different things depending on if you're introducing a function template or a generic lambda -- which is to say, two very similar contexts serving similar purposes!

Plus then... what would you do if you actually want a non-type template parameter? Just can't have one?

Comment: Can you give full example of:already has a meaning? I do not understand it. I tried this, but clang/gcc disagree if it is valid cpp https://godbolt.org/z/hghhjc

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You need a `auto operator <=>(T const &) =  default;` in your struct for that to work, which is still not supported by those compilers.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl [This](https://godbolt.org/z/Lu3Zsf) will be a vaild C++20 program, just not implemented yet. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/3jV_TB) is a valid C++11 program.

Comment: ah ok, if you have time put that in the A, since it is not clear to me that you were talking about using "alias"

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I wasn't talking about using aliases. I was talking about using _any_ type name. The example could've just been `template <int> void foo();`, works just fine.

Comment: OK, but that is not really realistic...but anyway I get your answer: sometimes <bla> means type named bla, and if it mean "variable" named bla it would be confusing...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl What's not really realistic? Having non-type template parameters of type `int`, or having non-type template parameters at all?

Comment: I apologize for bad phrasing... What I meant is that is not realistic to expect that people will use int as a new typename(in my version of lambda without typename), but I guess certain types like Time, or Size or Robot may be more confusing...

Comment: tl;dr I get your argument now, but I did not get it from the answer...(it was confusing that T is not defined as a type in the A)

Answer (score 3):

While conciseness is indeed a selling point of lambdas, it is not important enough to supersede the need for consistency. This is especially true for features involving templates, as they are harder to grasp than non-template language features.

In particular, the template syntax for generic lambdas has a narrow scope in the first place, i.e., most lambdas can live without it (in fact, the example you gave is a perfect example of not to use it as the function body doesn't instantiate a `T` or does something comparable). From [P0428](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r2.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> There are a **few** key reasons why the current syntax for defining generic lambdas is deemed insufficientby the author. The gist of it is that some things that can be done easily with normal functiontemplates require significant hoop jumping to be done with generic lambdas, or can’t be done at all.

Generic lambdas with `decltype` usage in their body are likely to be the most prominent clients of the new features. And replacing the `decltype`/`decay_t`-trickery with `<typename T>` seems more acceptable to me in terms of additional typing and conciseness.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply write

```
[]<T>(){ }
```

what is `T`?

A `typename`?
An `auto` value?

It seems to me that, in lambdas as in common functions, it's necessary explicit what is a template argument.

And if you can deduce that `T` is a type from the use (if it's used as first template argument for `std::vector` must be a type) why simplify only lambda syntax and not also the syntax of traditional template functions?